# Отображение ListView в Android Studio

Tags: android, listview, java, android-studio

Помогите новичку. Не могу разобраться с **ListView**.

Нарисовал в *main.xml*:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="373dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top" />
```

В *MainActivity.java*:

```
String[] names = { "Пример1", "Пример2" };

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);

public void setAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String> adapter) {
    this.adapter = adapter;
```

Сохранил, но в main.xml по-прежнему незаполненный данными список. Что делаю не так?

Comment: @Никита Авдеев, а разве сама студия должна динамически данные подгружать? По-моему, можно увидеть результат только после запуска приложения.

Comment: Ну так запусти приложение, и будет видно))

Comment: @Никита Авдеев, main.xml и не должен был список заполниться. Студия не выполняет ваш код. И не должна.

Comment: @metalurgus, из-за чего тогда ошибка? Почему приложение не запускается?

Comment: Как минимум я не вижу `lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: @katso, окей. Исправил.
    
    ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);

    public void setAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String> adapter) {
        this.adapter = adapter;

        lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: стактрейс почитайте, там написано, из за чего ошибка. Или вы первый раз под Андроид пишете?

Comment: @metalurgus, первый раз, и что такое Стактрейс?

Answer (score 2):

Вы не присвоили ListView адаптер:          `lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);`